# Need help with the REGULAR EXPRESSION (REGEX) to format the strings

Tags: regular-expressions

Just need to take off the unwanted characters from the erroneous string and need to store that as meaningful result.
parse/split the error data value into a list of strings of the numbers below using Apex regexes.

For example:
8620202%2F8620211%2F8622356 -> ['8620202','8620211','8622356']

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

You can split String by character '`%2F`' and array returned will be your result.

Try below code in [developer console](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_system_log.htm).

```
String sample = '8620202%2F8620211%2F8622356';
String[] strResult = sample.split('%2F');

For(String s : strResult)
{
    System.debug('-- Value --- '+s);
}
```